# Building a item-item matrix in java

Tags: java, matrix, hashmap

I am building a item-item matrix and have the data in the following format

```
    UserX item1,item2,item3
    userY item4,item5,item6
```

.....

i need to build matrix of the form

```
        item1   item2   item3   
 item1
 item2
 item3
```

What would be the best design and data structure to go about as i will be handling large amounts of data?

Currently i have been designing using Hashmaps. Is there any other better solution?

EDIT : The matrix will be used to store the association value of item1 to item 2,item3.... The end use would be to build something similar to Amazon recommendations.

Comment: You should post your code... how does the user influence the matrix or what values do you expect for a given combination (e.g. item1/item2)?

Comment: what do you need the matrix for? if it is for calculations, I suggest using matrix libraries such as Colt. If you are actually looking for a map between a pair to an item, I suggest creating a Pair class, and use it as a key.

Comment: What is the functional requirement behind this? do u want to which user has what items and/or all the users owning a given item?

Comment: home..The user will not have influence on the matrix now.. @amit, the matrix will be used to store the association value of item1 to item 2,item3.... The end use would be to build something similar to Amazon recommendations..

Comment: @learner - why doesn't use the faceted search capabilities provided by Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure that sprung to mind when I read your "matrix" requirement was Guava's [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html). I don't know if it's the most performant one ([HashBasedTable](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html), the "standard" implementation, uses hash tables), but it seems to be the easiest to manipulate for what you want to do (cleaner code).

That being said, I think you should look at real recommendation engines. In Java, you could look at [Apache Mahout Taste](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation). You could also use [Google's prediction API](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/).